# How to code a reverse 'Guess my Number' game in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a game where a player tries to guess a random number (see code below). Suggestions such as 'Too low...' and 'Too High...' are also provided. But what about reversing it and letting the computer guess a number that a player has selected. I have difficulty with this and I dont know why. I think I need a 'push' from someone but not the actual code as I need to attempt this myself. I would appreciate it if some would help me on this.

Here is the code(Python 3) where the player has to guess the number:

```
#Guess my Number - Exercise 3
#Limited to 5 guesses

import random 

attempts = 1
secret_number = random.randint(1,100)
isCorrect = False
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

while secret_number != guess and attempts < 6:

    if guess < secret_number:
        print("Higher...")
    elif guess > secret_number:
        print("Lower...")
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    attempts += 1

if attempts == 6:
    print("\nSorry you reached the maximum number of tries")
    print("The secret number was ",secret_number) 

else:
    print("\nYou guessed it! The number was " ,secret_number)
    print("You guessed it in ", attempts,"attempts")

input("\n\n Press the enter key to exit")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

at each iteration through your loop, you'll need a new `random.randint(low,high)`.  `low` and `high` can be figured out by collecting your computers guesses into 2 lists (`low_list`) and (`high_list`) based how the user responds when the computer tells the user it's guess.  Then you get `low` by `max(low_list)+1` and you get `high` by `min(high_list)-1`.  Of course, you'll have to initialize `low_list` and `high_list` with the lowest and highest numbers allowed.

You could just keep the lowest of the "too high" guesses and the highest of the "too_low" guesses instead of the lists.  It would be slightly more efficient and probably the same amount of work to code, but then you couldn't look back at the computer's guesses for fun :).

Comment: Thanks but I have not learnt how lists work yet. How can I do it without lists?

Comment: @fdama -- That's what my last paragraph explains.

Answer (score 1):

You begin with a range from the minimum allowed number to the maximum allowed number, because the unknown number could be anywhere in the range.

At each step, you need to choose a number to query, so dividing the space into two blocks; those on the wrong side of your query number will be dropped. The most efficient way to do this in the minimum number of queries is to bisect the space each time.

I suggest you restrict the game to integers, otherwise you'll end up with a lot of messing about with floating point values regarding tolerance and precision and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the range of numbers it could be is (a,b).

Think about how you would narrow down the range. You'd start by guessing in the middle. If your guess was low, you'd guess between your last guess and the top value. If it was high you'd guess between the lowest possible value and the last guess. By iteratively narrowing the range, eventually you'd find the number.

Here's some pseudo code for this:

```
loop{

guess = (a+b)/2

if high:
    b = guess - 1
else if low:
    a = guess + 1
else:
    guess = answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this with a different person, use a while loop and use print("<,>,="), then do an if statement. You need a max point, middlepoint and low point and to get the middle point you need to do midpoint=((highpoint=lowpoint)//2) and in the if statement you have to do change the maxpoint and lowpoint.